# Spark Scala reduceByKey - how to reference to keys specified in configuration file?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataset with the following schema:

```
  dataset.printSchema()
  |-- id: string (nullable = true)
  |-- feature1: double (nullable = true)
  |-- feature2: double (nullable = true)
  |-- feature3: double (nullable = true)
  |-- feature4: double (nullable = true)
```

In my application.conf I have defined a subset of keys which should be transformed using reduceByKey:

```
keyInfo {
    keysToBeTransformed = "feature1,feature2"
}
```

I can load these keys into my main object:

```
val config : Config = ConfigFactory.load()
val keys : Array[String] = config.getString("keyInfo.keysToBeTransformed").split(",")
```

For these keys, I need to compute the mean for each id in the dataset and collect the result into an array. Currently, I use the following approach:

```
    val meanFeature1 : Array[Double] = dataset.map(x => (x.id, x.feature1)).rdd
    .mapValues{z => (z,1)}
    .reduceByKey{(x,y) => (x._1 + y._1, x._2 + y._2)}
    .map( x => {
      val temp = x._2
      val total = temp._1
      val count = temp._2
      (x._1, total / count)
    }).collect().sortBy(_._1).map(_._2),

   val meanFeature2 : Array[Double] = dataset.map(x => (x.id, x.feature2)).rdd
    .mapValues{z => (z,1)}
    .reduceByKey{(x,y) => (x._1 + y._1, x._2 + y._2)}
    .map( x => {
      val temp = x._2
      val total = temp._1
      val count = temp._2
      (x._1, total / count)
    }).collect().sortBy(_._1).map(_._2)
```

The problem of the above approach is that it does not make a reference to the keys specified in my application.conf (the computation does not change dynamically when the keys are re-specified in the application.conf)

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `DataFrame` API is more suitable in this case, as it better supports dynamically accessing columns by name. And converting a `Dataset` into a `DataFrame` is trivial:

```
val averagesPerId: Array[Array[Double]] = dataset
  .groupBy("id") // this also converts to DataFrame
  .avg(keys: _*) // create average for each key - creates a "avg(featureX)" column for each featureX key
  .sort("id")
  .map(r => keys.map(col => r.getAs[Double](s"avg($col)"))) // map Rows into Array[Double], one for each ID
  .collect()

// transposing the result to create an array where each row relates to a single key,
// and mapping each row to its key:
val averagesPerKey: Map[String, Array[Double]] = keys.zip(averagesPerId.transpose(identity)).toMap

// for example, if `feature1` was in `keys`:
val meanFeature1 = averagesPerKey("feature1")
```

Comment: great, thanks! your solution is also much more performant as you only need to collect() once.

Answer (score 0):

Another similar solution I came up in the meantime would be the following:

```
val meanFeatures : Array[Array[Double]] = keys.map(col => {dataset
    .groupBy("id")
    .agg(avg(col))
    .as[(String,Double)]
    .sort("id")
    .collect().map(_._2)
})
val meanFeature1 : Array[Double] = meanFeatures(0)
```